# Вечные BSODы из-за svchost.exe

Tags: windows, bsod, windows-11

Ребят, накатил винду 11 для пробы и постоянно получаю BSODы при заходе на неё после Linux... В чём может быть проблема?

Вот вывод WinDbg:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22000.194 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Full address space is available

Dump completed successfully, progress percentage: 100

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 22000 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Edition build lab: 22000.1.amd64fre.co_release.210604-1628
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`1aa00000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`1b629710
Debug session time: Sat Oct  9 19:54:50.684 2021 (UTC + 5:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:26.421
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
.....................
Loading User Symbols
..................
Loading unloaded module list
.............
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
7: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED (ef)
        A critical system process died
Arguments:
Arg1: ffff818910029080, Process object or thread object
Arg2: 0000000000000000, If this is 0, a process died. If this is 1, a thread died.
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 4499

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 4909

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2874

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 18502

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 91

    Key  : CriticalProcessDied.Process
    Value: svchost.exe

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: co_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2021-06-04T16:28:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.22000.1


DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x1000

BUGCHECK_CODE:  ef

BUGCHECK_P1: ffff818910029080

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CRITICAL_PROCESS:  svchost.exe

IMAGE_NAME:  svchost.exe

MODULE_NAME: svchost

FAULTING_MODULE: 00007ff69f830000 svchost

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffb18f`53b19f48 fffff801`1b3af483     : 00000000`000000ef ffff8189`10029080 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffb18f`53b19f50 fffff801`1b294801     : ffff8189`10029080 ffff8189`11a48338 00000000`00000000 fffff801`1ad31bcb : nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+0x11b
ffffb18f`53b19fe0 fffff801`1b17bf94     : ffff8189`10029080 00000000`00000000 ffff8189`10029080 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspTerminateAllThreads+0x1b9d0d
ffffb18f`53b1a050 fffff801`1b17bc97     : 00000000`00000000 ffffb18f`53b1a159 ffff8189`0fc33040 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspTerminateProcess+0xe0
ffffb18f`53b1a090 fffff801`1b0e73b6     : 00000000`00000000 ffff8189`0fc33040 ffff8189`0feb0098 fffff801`1ac5b9d6 : nt!PsTerminateProcess+0x2b
ffffb18f`53b1a0c0 fffff801`1b0f73f4     : ffff8189`0feb0001 ffff8189`0feb0060 00000000`00000006 fffff801`1ac5b97b : nt!PspRemoveProcessFromJobChain+0x2a6
ffffb18f`53b1a1c0 fffff801`1b0e974e     : 00000000`00000000 ffff8189`0feb0060 00000000`00000000 fffff801`1b0e9612 : nt!PspTerminateProcessesJobCallback+0xb4
ffffb18f`53b1a220 fffff801`1b0e90d4     : ffff8189`0feb0060 ffff8189`0feb1060 fffff801`1b0f7340 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspCallJobHierarchyCallbacks+0xba
ffffb18f`53b1a270 fffff801`1b1b955f     : ffff8189`0fc33040 00000000`00000000 fffff801`1b0f7340 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspEnumJobsAndProcessesInJobHierarchy+0xf0
ffffb18f`53b1a2f0 fffff801`1b1b94d0     : 00000002`00000000 ffff8189`0feb1060 ffff8189`04eb2220 ffff8189`0fc33040 : nt!PspTerminateAllProcessesInJobHierarchy+0x5f
ffffb18f`53b1a330 fffff801`1b0ee320     : ffff8189`0feb1030 ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspJobClose+0xc0
ffffb18f`53b1a360 fffff801`1b0ee1a8     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00007ff7 fffff801`00000000 : nt!ObpDecrementHandleCount+0xd0
ffffb18f`53b1a410 fffff801`1b0ee035     : ffff8189`097d9078 fffff801`1ac5b9d6 00000000`00000000 ffff8189`0fc33040 : nt!ObCloseHandleTableEntry+0xe8
ffffb18f`53b1a4d0 fffff801`1b0e0265     : ffff8189`097d9040 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffff01 00000000`00000001 : nt!ExSweepHandleTable+0xd5
ffffb18f`53b1a580 fffff801`1b0e24d9     : ffffffff`ffffffff ffff8189`0fc21080 ffffb18f`53b1a5d0 fffff801`1b0d196c : nt!ObKillProcess+0x35
ffffb18f`53b1a5b0 fffff801`1b0ed863     : ffff8189`0fc2108
```

Никак не могу понять в чём же проблема... Судя по всему после запуска сразу сдыхает `svchost.exe` и всё, но с чем это связано? -_-

PS Ошибка вылезает всего одни раз после действий: Вошёл в линукс, поработал, вошёл под виндой. После одного перезапуска он больше не появляется

Comment: На Вирусы проверяли?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, раза 2 примерно. Dr Web никаких не находил. + это пошло сразу после установки. Я тестить начал только через день-два(ставил бетку сначала)

Comment: пишите в мелкософт об ошибке и откатывайтесь в 10-ку

Comment: @ArchDemon, да ошибка то не сильно мешает. Зашёл в линукс, перезагрузился под виндой, выкинуло, снова загрузился под винду и всё пашет. А вот написать им не могу... "Чат временно недоступен", а в community из-за номера телефона(смс не отправляют) зайти не даёт -_-